# OpenVino Performance - Neural Stick vs. CPU

Tags: opencv, intel, openvino

I'm seeing a significant difference in inference performance between my desktop CPU and when I run on the Neural Compute Stick 2 VPU - almost 500ms slower on VPU. This is the one line that takes the most time and has the biggest difference:

```
result = exec_net.infer( inputs={input_layer_ir: blob} )
```

My desktop is my gaming machine and has a nice fast Intel CPU. That said is this the expected order of magnitude difference between the VPU and CPU?

CPU speeds are really fast like .07 seconds and VPU is around .5.

It’s the road segmentation model from the open zoo samples.

Comment: Which one is faster?  What are the actual speeds of the two?  We don't know how much of a speed difference 500ms is if we don't know if it's out of 10 seconds or out of 1 second or what.  What size of data?  What actual model of desktop CPU?  There is a large range in terms of number of cores.

Comment: What kind of neural network? What kind of CPU?

Comment: people using GPUs/accelerators always forget there's gonna be latency and setup costs.

Comment: You are not including data movement timing from PC to Neural Stick right?

Answer (score 1):

Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2 (NCS 2) is a USB stick that offers you access to neural network functionality, without the need for large, expensive hardware. It is a plug-and-play device, so you are ready to start prototyping right away.

The performance of NCS 2 compared to the well-known CPUs or GPUs in the meaning of TFLOPS, it is still a hundred times lower. This behaviour is expected, so don’t rely on it as an external device to replace the CPU plugin.

Comment: If it has ~100x lower throughput than using a CPU to simulate a neural network, what's the point of it?  Is there some way it can use its limited TFLOPS more effectively than a CPU for some workloads other than the one in this question?

Comment: NCS 2 is designed to be a low cost, low power consumption and a part of mobile projects such as surveillance system for smart home.

Comment: Ok, so for things like plugging into a Raspberry Pi, not *for* prototyping on a desktop to run on something that will run on even beefier hardware than the desktop.  That makes sense given the form factor (just passive cooling without a lot of surface area).  The phrasing in your answer didn't correct that misunderstanding I picked up from the question.  You mean prototyping to see if your mobile/embedded use-case will meet its perf goals, by intentionally using just the compute stick instead of your desktop's full power.  Make sense. Thanks.